# @task(hosts=[...]) yields Context but -H yields Connection?

Tags: python, invoke, fabric, python-fabric-2

Python 3.8.2, Fabric 2.5.0, Paramiko 2.7.2, Invoke 1.4.1

Hello,

I have a fabfile which needs to handle hosts passed at the command-line (using `-H`) and hosts defined in the fabfile if `-H` was not passed. Here's an example of the issue I'm facing:

```py
target_group = None

@task
def prod(c):
    _env_handler(c, "prod")

def _env_handler(c, env_name):
    global target_group

    if not hasattr(c, 'host'):
        target_group = Group("somehost1.tld", "somehost2.tld")

@task(hosts=target_group)
def test(c):
    print(c)
```

If I run `fab prod test`:

```
<Context: <Config: {'run': {'asynch ...
```

If I run `fab -H 1,2 test`:

```
<Connection host=1>
<Connection host=2>
```

So, passing hosts using the `@task(hosts=[...]` decorator produces a c `Context` object, and using `-H` produces a c `Connection` object.

I know using a task (`prod(c)`) to wrap environment logic may be questionable...but is there a way to ensure the task (`test(c)`) always receives a `Connection` object...or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Thanks.

Edit: I've also tried directly passing a hosts list `(e.g. @task(hosts=["somehost1.tld", "somehost2.tld"]))` with the same result.

Edit: Here's the current workaround, but it's obviously not ideal if you have a lot of tasks:

```py
@task
def test(c):
    if not hasattr(c, 'host'):
        for c in target_group:
            test(c)
    else:
        logging.info(f"Targeting {c.host}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround using a custom task decorator:

```py
def _task_handler(func):
    @task
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(c):
        if not hasattr(c, 'host'):
            for c in target_group:
                func(c)
        else:
            func(c)

    return wrapper
```